# Trigger MySQL - Erro sintaxe: DECLARE @venda INT' at line 3

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo uma TRIGGER no MySQL para que no momento de uma inserção na tabela "Itens_venda" o campo "vendido" na tabela produto seja alterado para "sim". Como uma venda pode possuir vários itens, resolvi trabalhar com um cursor (nunca utilizei antes).Fiz o cursor após algumas pesquisas e, ao tentar executá-lo, o SGBD (PHPMyAdmin) informou o seguinte erro: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @venda INT' at line 3".
Eu não sei onde estou errando na sintaxe. Alguém poderia me dizer onde estou errando na sintaxe... se sim, tem mais algum erro?

Obrigado por responder, Guilherme! Após a sua resposta, refiz a estrutura da TRIGGUER. Mas, está aparecendo um único erro agora: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS BEGIN DECLARE @venda INT, @codigo_produto int, cursor_itens CURSOR ' at line 3" 
A nova trigguer:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER atualiza_produto 
    AFTER INSERT ON itens_venda
    BEGIN
         DECLARE @venda INT,  @codigo_produto int, cursor_itens CURSOR FOR SELECT produto_codigo FROM itens_venda WHERE id_venda = @venda
         SET @venda = ('SELECT id_venda FROM INSERTED')
         OPEN cursor_itens
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_itens INTO @codigo_produto
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE produto SET vendido = 's' WHERE codigo = @codigo_produto
                END
        CLOSE cursor_itens
        DEALLOCATE cursor_itens          
 END
 $$
```

Comment: Eu acho que está faltando o BEGIN antes de DECLARE

Comment: Oi, Guilherme, obrigado por responder! Eu mudei a estrutura e deixei assim:

Comment: Respondi a pergunta e então percebi que você está usando @@FETCH_STATUS que é sintaxe do SQL Server. No MySql é totalmente diferente. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

O loop no MySql não usa @@FETCH_STATUS como no SQL Server. Da mesma forma os triggers after insert são definidos de outra forma. Me parece que ficará muito mais simples que o seu código com cursor:

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualiza_produto 
AFTER INSERT 
ON itens_venda FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE produto SET vendido = 's' WHERE codigo = NEW.produto_codigo;

END
```

O trigger é chamado para cada linha inserida e você pode acessar o valor novo inserido usando a sintaxe `NEW.nome_do_campo`.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, amigo. funcionou sem o cursor! ;)

Comment: @MatheusMinguini não esqueça de definir a resposta como a correta, senão ficará ainda em aberto a questão.